# In noUiSlider: Moving the slider by clicking pips now working

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I am trying to move the slider by clicking on pips. However on clicking a pip the slider moves to the starting position, when it should instead move to the position where the pip was clicked. Can anyone help?

```html
<div id="slider-pips" style="top: 0px; right: 1px; margin: 10px 25px;"></div>
```

```js
var pipsSlider = document.getElementById('slider-pips');
noUiSlider.create(pipsSlider, {
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  start: [50],
  pips: {
    mode: 'count',
    values: 5
  }
});

var pips = pipsSlider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-value');

function clickOnPip() {
  var value = Number(pipsSlider.getAttribute('data-value'));
  pipsSlider.noUiSlider.set(value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < pips.length; i++) {
  pips[i].style.cursor = 'pointer';
  pips[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnPip);
}
```

Demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/xfrtho8m/1/

I am trying to implement it like this: 
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-click-pips

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're trying to set the value of the slider to a `data` attribute which doesn't exist.

Instead you simply need to read the text of the clicked 'pip' and set the value to that:

```
function clickOnPip() {
  var value = parseInt(this.innerText, 10);
  pipsSlider.noUiSlider.set(value);
}
```

```js
var pipsSlider = document.getElementById('slider-pips');

noUiSlider.create(pipsSlider, {
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  start: [50],
  pips: {
    mode: 'count',
    values: 5
  }
});
var pips = pipsSlider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-value');

function clickOnPip() {
  var value = parseInt(this.innerText, 10);
  pipsSlider.noUiSlider.set(value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < pips.length; i++) {
  pips[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnPip);
}
```

```css
#slider-pips {
  top: 0;
  right: 1px;
  margin: 10px 25px;
}

.noUi-value {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.5.1/nouislider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.5.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-pips" style=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer solves the problem here, the noUiSlider version used in the provided demo is `8.5.1`. The `data-value` attributes were added in noUiSlider `11.0.0` (as mentioned in the documentation linked in the question). Upgrading noUiSlider would have the originally provided code working.

Answer (score 0):

For v11.0.0 onwards as mentioned you need to use data attributes. This works:

```
var pips = pipsSlider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-value');

function clickOnPip() {
    var value = Number(this.dataset.value);
    pipsSlider.noUiSlider.set(value);
}
    
for (var i = 0; i < pips.length; i++) {
    pips[i].style.cursor = 'pointer';
    pips[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnPip);
}
```